# Missing characters when printing a string in terminal

Tags: python, printing, terminal, carriage-return

I'm printing a string to the terminal (iTerm on OSX).

My code looks like this:

```py
print("1234567890")
print(summary)
print("XX" + summary)
print(ord(summary[0]), summary[0])
print(ord(summary[1]), summary[1])
```

The output looks like this:

[image: terminal output]

Note how the first two characters from any print statement containing that `summary` string are deleted. I've printed out the first two characters and their ASCII codes, and they are what I'd expect (E and x).

Printing strings has never been a problem before.

I can't provide an example of the `summary` string, but if I run

```
print(repr(summary))
```

it shows that there is `\r \r` at the end. Could that affect the first two characters?
What could I possibly look at to start debugging this?

Comment: Do a `print(repr(summary))` to see if there are any "funny" chars like a carriage return `\r` in there.

Comment: `print(repr(summary)` shows there is `\r \r` on the end. How would that affect the first two characters?

Comment: The first one moves the cursor back to the start of the line, then the two white space chars override what was there before. How such chars are handled may depend on the terminal and system you are using

Comment: Thanks. I've written this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(repr(summary)
```

shows:

```
'Example from ma....\r \r '
```

On iTerm on OSX, the first `\r` returns to the start of the line, the subsequent space overwrites the `E`. I don't entirely understand how the `x` gets erased, since I would have thought the next `\r` returns to the start of the line again.

Nevertheless, this was enough to fix the problem.